# Bad request from Login api endpoint of Reqres.in

Tags: postman

I was testing the API's of https://reqres.in

Particularly the login endpoint : /api/login
However I am not able to hit the endpoint

```
{
    "error": "Missing email or username"
}
```

This is the endpoint. https://reqres.in/api/login
I select post from the list of types. And in the raw body I send in

```
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}
```

I don't see where I am wrong. Can anybody point out the solution?
Also this is the documentation link of the above mentioned API endpoint :
[Link](https://reqres.in/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Remember select JSON***. It works for me:
[image]

I think that you had "Text". I hope this helps you out :)